# Generic rounded button for all rouned view

Tags: android, android-drawable

> I have created a rounded button like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">


    <solid android:color="@color/theme_chocolate_level" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>

    <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp"/>

</shape>
```

I have to use `multiple rounded button` but all are in different color. Is there an xml way to use a single generic rounded button for all my buttons. Otherwise I have to create **multiple drawable and only change solid color attribute**

```
          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_generic_btn"
            />
```

And I know I can do it programatically but I have a keen interest to do it via xml.

**I don't want to do it Programmatically. I know that way**

Comment: Tried setting backgroundTint attribute in xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tint you background using backgroundTint attr in your view in xml.
Since this attribute was added in API 21 you need to set it with custom prefix.

In your root view: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
and then on view: `app:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"`

Comment: HellBoy does it have support for api 14

Comment: It works on api 10 so I guess it will work on api 14 as well

Comment: Did you use app prefix insted of android? I just realize that I made mistake in my answer. For my it works perfectly down to Gingerbread with custom prefix